# Passing an object or String to controller before initialiation

Tags: java, javafx

I have a class that contains information based on which the title text in the next scene will be modified. So I need to pass the Object or at least a String to the new scene, using which I'll update the text in the next scene during Initialization.

```
void sceneSwitch(Event event, String fxmlName, Class child){
        String fxmlPath = "gui/resources/fxml/";
        Node node = (Node) event.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();

        FXMLLoader sceneLoader = fxmlLoadErrorHandler(fxmlPath + fxmlName, child); //This sets up the FXMLLoader
        Parent newScene = fxmlLoadErrorHandler(sceneLoader); 

        /* The last line above is basically the .load() function, but this already
        launches the Initialize function, in which I need to use 'session' Object
        which I only yet set below via setActive */

        CoreController controller = sceneLoader.getController();
        controller.setActive(session);

        Scene scene = null;
        if(newScene != null) {
            scene = new Scene(newScene);
        }

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

So is there any way for me to do what I'm trying to here? It would be sufficient to just send a String to it. I thought of defining a function in the CoreController that I'll run as soon as I set Session before the scene shows, but CoreController is an abstract Class and I don't have access to modifying the objects in the subclass.

Comment: You could expose a method in the abstract class that sub-classes would override; the overrides would call the super implementation as well as do their own thing. Another option is to not use `fx:controller` and instead call `FXMLLoader.setController` before loading. A third option is to use a [controller factory](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setControllerFactory(javafx.util.Callback)).

Comment: I hope your `fxmlLoadErrorHandler` methods rethrow exceptions wrapped in some kind of `RuntimeException`. Otherwise any error happening in one of the invocations inevitably results in an exception in the `sceneSwitch` method...

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Slaw in a comment in response to the question. Thanks! I feel embarassed I didn't think of this.

"You could expose a method in the abstract class that sub-classes would override; the overrides would call the super implementation as well as do their own thing. Another option is to not use fx:controller and instead call FXMLLoader.setController before loading. A third option is to use a controller factory."